# Edit distance implementation

Tags: algorithm, rust, dynamic-programming, edit-distance

This problem is taken from the book *Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition By Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein*:

> In order to transform one source string of text *x[1..m]* to a target
>   string *y[1..n]*, we can perform various transformation operations.
>   Our goal is, given *x* and *y*, to produce a series of transformations
>   that change x to y. We use an array  ́*z*—assumed to be large enough to
>   hold all the characters it will need—to hold the intermediate results.
>   Initially, *z* is empty, and at termination, we should have *z[j] = y[j]*
>    for *j = 1, 2,..., n*. We maintain current indices *i* into *x* and *j* into
>   *z*, and the operations are allowed to alter *z* and these indices.
>   Initially, *i = j = 1*. We are required to examine every character in *x*
>   during the transformation, which means that at the end of the sequence
>   of transformation operations, we must have *i = m + 1*.
>
> We may choose from among six transformation operations:
>
> **Copy** a character from *x* to *z* by setting  ́*z[j] = x[i]* and then incrementing both *i* and *j*. This operation examines *x[i]*.
>
> **Replace** a character from *x* by another character *c*, by setting *z[j] = c*, and then incrementing both *i* and *j* . This operation examines *x[i]*.
>
> **Delete** a character from *x* by incrementing *i* but leaving *j* alone. This operation examines *x[i]*.
>
> **Insert** the character *c* into *z* by setting *z[j] = c* and then incrementing *j* , but leaving *i* alone. This operation examines no
>   characters of *x*.
>
> **Twiddle** (i.e., exchange) the next two characters by copying them from *x* to *z* but in the opposite order; we do so by setting *z[j] = x[i*
>   *+ 1]* and  ́*z[j + 1] = x[i]* and then setting *i = i + 2* and *j = j +* *2*. This operation examines *x[i]* and *x[i + 1]*.
>
> **Kill** the remainder of *x* by setting *i = m + 1*. This operation examines all characters in *x* that have not yet been examined. This
>   operation, if performed, must be the final operation.
>
> **a.** Given two sequences x[1..m] and y[1..n] and set of transformation
>   operation costs, the edit distance from x to y is the cost of the
>   least expensive operation sequence that transforms x to y. Describe a
>   dynamic-programming algorithm that finds the edit distance from
>   x[1..m] to y[1..n] and prints an optimal operation sequence. Analyze
>   the running time and space requirements of your algorithm

My solution is \$O(nm + m+n)\$.

### Code:

```
extern crate rand;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::VecDeque;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
enum EditOp {
    Copy,
    Replace,
    Delete,
    Insert,
    Twiddle,
    Kill,
}

impl EditOp {
    fn valid(&self,
             i       : usize,
             j       : usize,
             iprev   : char,
             jprev   : char,
             icurrent: char,
             jcurrent: char) -> bool {

        let threshold = |p| i != p || j == p; 
        match *self {
            EditOp::Copy    => threshold(1) 
                                && icurrent == jcurrent,

            EditOp::Replace => threshold(1),
            EditOp::Delete  => i > 1,

            EditOp::Twiddle => i > 1 && j > 1
                                && threshold(2)
                                && icurrent == jprev
                                && iprev == jcurrent,
            _ => true,                                                          
        }
    }

    fn displacement(&self) -> (usize, usize) {
        match *self {
            EditOp::Copy    => (1, 1),
            EditOp::Replace => (1, 1),
            EditOp::Delete  => (1, 0),
            EditOp::Insert  => (0, 1),
            EditOp::Twiddle => (2, 2),
            EditOp::Kill    => (0, 0),    
        }
    }

    fn apply(&self, 
             from_itr: &mut std::str::Chars, 
             to_itr  : &mut std::str::Chars, 
             result  : &mut String) {
        match *self {
            EditOp::Copy    => { 
                result.push(from_itr.next().unwrap());
                to_itr.next();

            },
            EditOp::Replace => {
                result.push(to_itr.next().unwrap());
                from_itr.next();
            },
            EditOp::Delete  => {
                from_itr.next();
            },
            EditOp::Insert  => {
                result.push(to_itr.next().unwrap());
            },
            EditOp::Twiddle => {
                let second = from_itr.next().unwrap();
                let first = from_itr.next().unwrap();
                result.push(first);
                result.push(second);
                to_itr.next();
                to_itr.next();
            },
            EditOp::Kill => {},
        }
    }
}


fn create_tables(from_len: usize, 
                 to_len  : usize, 
                 costs   : &HashMap<EditOp, usize>) 
-> (Vec<Vec<EditOp>>, Vec<Vec<usize>>) {    

    let mut op_table   = vec![ vec![EditOp::Kill; to_len]; from_len ];
    let mut cost_table = vec![ vec![0usize; to_len]; from_len ];
    let delete_cost    = costs.get(&EditOp::Delete).map(|c| *c).unwrap_or(0);

    for (i, c) in (1.. from_len).map(|i|(i, i * delete_cost)) {
        cost_table[i][0] = c;
        op_table[i][0]   = EditOp::Delete;
    } 
    (op_table , cost_table)
}

fn edit_distance(from : &str, 
                 to   : &str, 
                 costs: &HashMap<EditOp, usize>) 
-> (usize, VecDeque<EditOp>){

    if costs.is_empty() {
        panic!("map of costs is empty");
    }

    let from_len = from.chars().count(); 
    let to_len   = to.chars().count();

    let (mut op_table, mut cost_table) = create_tables(from_len + 1, 
                                                       to_len + 1, 
                                                       costs);
    let (mut lasti, mut lastj)         = (' ', ' ');

    for (i, ichar) in from.chars().enumerate() {
        for (j, jchar) in to.chars().enumerate() {
            let (i, j) = (i + 1, j + 1);
            let (op, cost) = costs.iter()
                .filter(|&(x, _)| !x.eq(&EditOp::Kill))
                .filter(|&(x, _)| x.valid(i, j, lasti, lastj, 
                                          ichar, jchar))
                .map(|(x, c)| {
                    let (di, dj) = x.displacement();
                    (x, cost_table[i - di][j - dj] + c)
                })
                .min_by_key(|&(_, c)| c)
                .unwrap(); 

            cost_table[i][j] = cost;
            op_table[i][j] = *op;
            lastj = jchar;
        }
        lasti = ichar;
    }


    let no_kill_cost    = cost_table[from_len][to_len];
    let (i, cost, kill) = costs.get(&EditOp::Kill)
                               .map(|kc| min_with_kill(&cost_table, 
                                                       from_len, 
                                                       to_len, *kc))
                               .unwrap_or((from_len, no_kill_cost, None));

    (cost, build_operations(kill, &op_table, i, to_len))
}


fn edit(from: &str, to: &str, ops: &VecDeque<EditOp>) -> String {   
    let mut result   = String::new();
    let mut from_itr = from.chars();
    let mut to_itr   = to.chars();

    for op in ops {
        op.apply(&mut from_itr, &mut to_itr, &mut result);      
    }
    result
}



fn min_with_kill(cost_table: &Vec<Vec<usize>>, 
                 from_size : usize, 
                 to_size   : usize, 
                 kill_cost : usize ) -> (usize, usize, Option<EditOp>) {

    let no_kill_cost  = cost_table[from_size][to_size];
    (1..from_size).map(|i|(i, cost_table[i][to_size] + kill_cost) )
                  .map(|(i, c)|(i, c, Some(EditOp::Kill)))
                  .chain(Some((from_size, no_kill_cost, None)).into_iter())
                  .min_by_key(|&(_, cost, _)| cost).unwrap() 
}

fn build_operations(kill    : Option<EditOp>, 
                    op_table: &Vec<Vec<EditOp>>, 
                    i       : usize, 
                    j       : usize) -> VecDeque<EditOp> {

    let itr = std::iter::repeat(()).scan((i, j), |s,_| {
            let op       = op_table[s.0][s.1]; 
            let (id, jd) = op.displacement();
            *s = (s.0 - id, s.1 - jd); 
            Some(op)
    }).take_while(|op| !op.eq(&EditOp::Kill));

    let mut stack = VecDeque::new();
    for op in kill.into_iter().chain(itr) {
        stack.push_front(op);
    }
    stack
}




fn main() {

 let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(EditOp::Copy, 2);
    map.insert(EditOp::Replace, 3);
    map.insert(EditOp::Delete, 2);
    map.insert(EditOp::Insert, 4);
    map.insert(EditOp::Twiddle, 1);
    map.insert(EditOp::Kill, 1);


    let from = "▓▓▓▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▓▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓\n\
                ▒▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░▓\n\
                ▒▓░░░░▓░░░░▓\n\
                ▓░░░░░░▓░▓░▓\n\
                ▓░░░░░░▓░░░▓\n\
                ▓░░▓░░░▓▓▓▓\n\
                ▒▓░░░░▓▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▓▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▓▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓\n\
                ▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▓";


    let to = "│▒│ /▒/\n\
              │▒│/▒/\n\
              │▒/▒/─┬─┐\n\
              │▒│▒|▒│▒│\n\
              ┌┴─┴─┐-┘─┘\n\
              │▒┌──┘▒▒▒│\n\
              └┐▒▒▒▒▒▒  ";

    let (c, s) = edit_distance(&from, &to, &map);  
    let result = edit(&from, &to, &s);


    println!("cost = {}", c);
    println!("{:?}", s);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

### Test:

```
use rand::Rng;

fn random_string(size: usize) -> String {
    (0..size).map(|_|rand::random::<char>()).collect()
}
#[test]
fn test_for_accurate_edition(){

    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(EditOp::Copy, 2);
    map.insert(EditOp::Replace, 3);
    map.insert(EditOp::Delete, 2);
    map.insert(EditOp::Insert, 4);
    map.insert(EditOp::Twiddle, 1);
    map.insert(EditOp::Kill, 1);

    let size_generator = || rand::thread_rng().gen_range(100, 500);
    for _ in 0..100 {
        let from = random_string(size_generator());
        let to = random_string(size_generator());
        let (_, s) = edit_distance(&from, &to, &map);  
        let result = edit(&from, &to, &s);
        assert_eq!(to, result);          
     }
}
```

Comment: [Follow-up question](/q/142963/9357)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a lightweight review...

1. You can combine imports with `{}`: `use std::collections::{HashMap, VecDeque};`
2. Consider importing enum variants in methods that exhaustively match on a lot of them. This helps avoid duplication and rightward pushing of code.
3. Accept a generic type that implements an iterator, instead of the specific `std::str::Chars`.
4. Introduce more and unique types, especially when you have repeated parallel names (`i`, `iprev`, `icurrent`). This also allows you to move functionality into methods.
5. Introduce type aliases. This is a tiny step towards official types, but gives an opportunity to introduce names and shorten them.
6. Instead of `VecDeque`, use a normal `Vec`, then you can use `Iterator::collect` and reverse it.
7. Use `a == &b` instead of `a.eq(&b)`.
8. I always recommend using `expect` instead of `unwrap`. When the panic happens, you will be much happier having some context of where the failure is.
9. Maybe introduce a dedicated struct for the cost mapping. Then you can implement `Default`, and there's no chance of missing a key.
10. Use `&[T]` instead of `&Vec<T>`. Faster and more usable.
11. [Clippy] Combine identical `match` arms with `Foo | Bar`.
12. [Clippy] Use `map_or` instead of `map().unwrap_or`.
13. [Clippy] Can use `cloned` instead of `|x| *x`.
14. [Clippy] Calls to `edit` and `edit_distance` have extra references.
15. Check out [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt), which, let's say *disagrees*, with some of your style choices.

Unfortunately, I found the code very dense, which made reading over it fairly difficult. It's possible some more verbose names could help. Here's a cherry-picked sample of code that takes a second to mentally process :

```
.map(|(x, c)| {
    let (di, dj) = x.displacement();
    (x, cost_table[i - di][j - dj] + c)
})
```

---

```
extern crate rand;

use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
enum EditOp {
    Copy,
    Replace,
    Delete,
    Insert,
    Twiddle,
    Kill,
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct FindBetterName {
    idx: usize,
    prev: char,
    current: char,
}

impl FindBetterName {
    fn valid_twiddle(&self, other: &FindBetterName) -> bool {
        self.idx > 1 && other.idx > 1 && self.current == other.prev && self.prev == other.current
    }
}

impl EditOp {
    fn valid(&self, i: FindBetterName, j: FindBetterName) -> bool {
        use EditOp::*;

        let threshold = |p| i.idx != p || j.idx == p;

        match *self {
            Copy => threshold(1) && i.current == j.current,
            Replace => threshold(1),
            Delete => i.idx > 1,
            Twiddle => threshold(2) && i.valid_twiddle(&j),
            _ => true,
        }
    }

    fn displacement(&self) -> (usize, usize) {
        use EditOp::*;

        match *self {
            Copy | Replace => (1, 1),
            Delete => (1, 0),
            Insert => (0, 1),
            Twiddle => (2, 2),
            Kill => (0, 0),
        }
    }

    fn apply<F, T>(&self, mut from_itr: F, mut to_itr: T, result: &mut String)
        where F: Iterator<Item = char>,
              T: Iterator<Item = char>
    {
        use EditOp::*;

        match *self {
            Copy => {
                result.push(from_itr.next().unwrap());
                to_itr.next();
            }
            Replace => {
                result.push(to_itr.next().unwrap());
                from_itr.next();
            }
            Delete => {
                from_itr.next();
            }
            Insert => {
                result.push(to_itr.next().unwrap());
            }
            Twiddle => {
                let second = from_itr.next().unwrap();
                let first = from_itr.next().unwrap();
                result.push(first);
                result.push(second);
                to_itr.next();
                to_itr.next();
            }
            Kill => {}
        }
    }
}

type CostMap = HashMap<EditOp, usize>;

fn create_tables(from_len: usize,
                 to_len: usize,
                 costs: &CostMap)
                 -> (Vec<Vec<EditOp>>, Vec<Vec<usize>>) {
    let mut op_table = vec![ vec![EditOp::Kill; to_len]; from_len ];
    let mut cost_table = vec![ vec![0usize; to_len]; from_len ];
    let delete_cost = costs.get(&EditOp::Delete).cloned().unwrap_or(0);

    for (i, c) in (1..from_len).map(|i| (i, i * delete_cost)) {
        cost_table[i][0] = c;
        op_table[i][0] = EditOp::Delete;
    }

    (op_table, cost_table)
}

fn edit_distance(from: &str, to: &str, costs: &CostMap) -> (usize, Operations) {
    if costs.is_empty() {
        panic!("map of costs is empty");
    }

    let from_len = from.chars().count();
    let to_len = to.chars().count();

    let (mut op_table, mut cost_table) = create_tables(from_len + 1, to_len + 1, costs);
    let (mut lasti, mut lastj) = (' ', ' ');

    for (i, ichar) in from.chars().enumerate() {
        for (j, jchar) in to.chars().enumerate() {
            let (i, j) = (i + 1, j + 1);
            let ii = FindBetterName {
                idx: i,
                prev: lasti,
                current: ichar,
            };
            let jj = FindBetterName {
                idx: j,
                prev: lastj,
                current: jchar,
            };

            let (op, cost) = costs.iter()
                .filter(|&(x, _)| x != &EditOp::Kill)
                .filter(|&(x, _)| x.valid(ii, jj))
                .map(|(x, c)| {
                    let (di, dj) = x.displacement();
                    (x, cost_table[i - di][j - dj] + c)
                })
                .min_by_key(|&(_, c)| c)
                .unwrap();

            cost_table[i][j] = cost;
            op_table[i][j] = *op;
            lastj = jchar;
        }
        lasti = ichar;
    }

    let no_kill_cost = cost_table[from_len][to_len];
    let (i, cost, kill) = costs.get(&EditOp::Kill)
        .map_or((from_len, no_kill_cost, None), |kc| {
            min_with_kill(&cost_table, from_len, to_len, *kc)
        });

    (cost, build_operations(kill, &op_table, i, to_len))
}

type Operations = Vec<EditOp>;
type OperationsSlice<'a> = &'a [EditOp];

fn edit(from: &str, to: &str, ops: OperationsSlice) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    let mut from_itr = from.chars();
    let mut to_itr = to.chars();

    for op in ops {
        op.apply(&mut from_itr, &mut to_itr, &mut result);
    }
    result
}

fn min_with_kill(cost_table: &[Vec<usize>],
                 from_size: usize,
                 to_size: usize,
                 kill_cost: usize)
                 -> (usize, usize, Option<EditOp>) {

    let no_kill_cost = cost_table[from_size][to_size];
    (1..from_size)
        .map(|i| (i, cost_table[i][to_size] + kill_cost))
        .map(|(i, c)| (i, c, Some(EditOp::Kill)))
        .chain(Some((from_size, no_kill_cost, None)).into_iter())
        .min_by_key(|&(_, cost, _)| cost)
        .unwrap()
}

fn build_operations(kill: Option<EditOp>,
                    op_table: &[Vec<EditOp>],
                    i: usize,
                    j: usize)
                    -> Operations {

    let itr = std::iter::repeat(())
        .scan((i, j), |s, _| {
            let op = op_table[s.0][s.1];
            let (id, jd) = op.displacement();
            *s = (s.0 - id, s.1 - jd);
            Some(op)
        })
        .take_while(|op| op != &EditOp::Kill);

    let mut stack: Vec<_> = kill.into_iter().chain(itr).collect();
    stack.reverse();
    stack
}


fn main() {
    let mut cost_map = HashMap::new();
    cost_map.insert(EditOp::Copy, 2);
    cost_map.insert(EditOp::Replace, 3);
    cost_map.insert(EditOp::Delete, 2);
    cost_map.insert(EditOp::Insert, 4);
    cost_map.insert(EditOp::Twiddle, 1);
    cost_map.insert(EditOp::Kill, 1);


    let from = "▓▓▓▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▓▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓\n\
                ▒▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░▓\n\
                ▒▓░░░░▓░░░░▓\n\
                ▓░░░░░░▓░▓░▓\n\
                ▓░░░░░░▓░░░▓\n\
                ▓░░▓░░░▓▓▓▓\n\
                ▒▓░░░░▓▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▓▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▓▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓\n\
                ▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓\n\
                ▒▒▓▒▒▒▒▒▓";


    let to = "│▒│ /▒/\n\
              │▒│/▒/\n\
              │▒/▒/─┬─┐\n\
              │▒│▒|▒│▒│\n\
              ┌┴─┴─┐-┘─┘\n\
              │▒┌──┘▒▒▒│\n\
              └┐▒▒▒▒▒▒  ";

    let (c, s) = edit_distance(from, to, &cost_map);
    let result = edit(from, to, &s);

    println!("cost = {}", c);
    println!("{:?}", s);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems my solution is incorrect for some inputs.

The main problem is in the `valid` and `create_tables` functions.

For some reason I added a several conditions in `valid` so that `i` will reach zero always after `j` and this is wrong. For example `"a" -> "ha"` with insert and copy should be valid. But for this to work properly all `j` so that `i == 0` most have insert in the table (The only way to edit an empty string is with insert).

So `valid` and `create_table` will end up like this:

```
fn create_tables(from_len: usize, 
                 to_len  : usize, 
                 costs   : &HashMap<EditOp, usize>) 
-> (Vec<Vec<EditOp>>, Vec<Vec<usize>>) {    

    let mut op_table   = vec![ vec![EditOp::Kill; to_len]; from_len ];
    let mut cost_table = vec![ vec![0usize; to_len]; from_len ];
    let delete_cost    = *costs.get(&EditOp::Delete).expect("delete most be in costs");
    let insert_cost    = *costs.get(&EditOp::Insert).expect("insert most be in costs");

    for (i, c) in (1.. from_len).map(|i|(i, i * delete_cost)) {
        cost_table[i][0] = c;
        op_table[i][0]   = EditOp::Delete;
    }
    for (j, c) in (1.. to_len).map(|j|(j, j * insert_cost)) {
        cost_table[0][j] = c;
        op_table[0][j]   = EditOp::Insert;
    }  
    (op_table , cost_table)
}

 fn valid(&self,
             i       : usize,
             j       : usize,
             iprev   : char,
             jprev   : char,
             icurrent: char,
             jcurrent: char) -> bool {

        match *self {
            EditOp::Copy    => icurrent == jcurrent,
            EditOp::Twiddle => i > 1 && j > 1
                                && icurrent == jprev
                                && iprev == jcurrent,
            _ => true,                                                          
        }
    }
```