# Edit distance (Optimal Alignment) - follow up

Tags: algorithm, rust, bioinformatics, edit-distance

This is a follow up of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142275/edit-distance-implementation)

**Optimal substructure of ED:**

Here is the reasoning behind my solution:

let \$x = (\alpha _{1},\alpha _{2},\alpha _{3},...,\alpha _{m})\$ and \$y = (\beta_{1},\beta_{2},\beta_{3},...,\beta_{n})\$.

We define \$c(i,j)\$ for \$ 0\leq i\leq m\$ and \$0\leq j\leq n\$ as the minimum edit distance to transform \$(\alpha _{1},...,\alpha _{i})\$ to \$(\beta_{1},...,\beta _{j})\$ without kill:

For \$1\leq i\leq m\$ and \$1\leq j\leq n\$:

\$c(i,j) = min\left\{\begin{matrix} c(i-1,j)+cost(delete) \phantom{-----------}
\\ c(i,j-1)+cost(insert) \phantom{-----------}
\\ \left\{\begin{matrix}c(i-1,j-1) + cost(copy) \hspace{5mm} if \hspace{2mm}\alpha _{i} = \beta _{j} 
\\ \infty \hspace{5cm} otherwise
\end{matrix}\right. \phantom{----}
\\ c(i-1,j-1)+cost(replace) \phantom{---------}
\\\left\{\begin{matrix}c(i-2,j-2) + cost(twiddle)\phantom{-------}\newline if \hspace{2mm} i >  1 \hspace{2mm} \wedge \hspace{2mm}j >  1 \hspace{2mm} \wedge \hspace{2mm} \alpha _{i} = \beta _{j-1} \hspace{2mm} \wedge \hspace{2mm}\alpha _{i-1} = \beta _{j} \\ \infty \hspace{6cm} otherwise \end{matrix} \right.\phantom{--} \end{matrix} \right.\$

For \$1\leq i\leq m\$ and \$j = 0\$:

\$c(i,j)=c(i-1,j)\;+\cos t(delete)\$

For \$1\leq j\leq n\$ and \$i = 0\$:

\$c(i,j)=c(i,j-1)\;+\cos t(insert)\$

For \$i=0\$ and \$j = 0\$:

\$c(i,j)=0\$

Then let \$k(i,j)\$ be the minimum edit distance with kill:

\$k(i,j)= min\left\{\begin{matrix}c(i,j) \phantom{------------------}
\\ min(\{c(1,j), c(2,j), ...,c(i-1,j)\})+cost(kill)
\end{matrix}\right.\$

**Question part 2:**

This is taken from the book *Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition By Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein* and is the second part of the same problem:

> The edit-distance problem generalizes the problem of aligning two DNA
>   sequences. There are several methods for measuring the similarity of
>   two DNA sequences by aligning them. One such method to align two
>   sequences \$x\$ and \$y\$ consists of inserting spaces at arbitrary
>   locations in the two sequences (including at either end) so that the
>   resulting sequences \$x'\$ and \$y'\$ have the same length but do not
>   have a space in the same position (i.e., for no position \$j\$ are
>   both \$x'[j]\$ and \$y'[j]\$  a space). Then we assign a “score” to
>   each position. Position \$j\$ receives a score as follows:
>
> - \$+1\$ if \$x'[j] = y'[j]\$ and neither is a space,
> - \$-1\$ if \$x'[j] ≠ y'[j]\$  and neither is a space,
> - \$-2\$ if either \$x'[j]\$  or \$y'[j]\$ is a space.
>
> The score for the alignment is the sum of the scores of the individual
>   positions. For example, given the sequences x = GATCGGCAT and y =
>   CAATGTGAATC, one alignment is
>
> G ATCG GCAT 
>   CAAT GTGAATC 
>   - *++*+*+  -++*
>
> A \$+\$ under a position indicates a score of \$+1\$ for that
>   position, a \$-\$ indicates a score of \$-1\$, and a \$*\$ indicates
>   a score of \$-2\$, so that this alignment has a total score of
>  \$6·1- 2·1 - 4·2 = 4\$.
>
> b. Explain how to cast the problem of finding an optimal alignment as
>   an edit distance problem using a subset of the transformation
>   operations copy, replace,delete, insert, twiddle, and kill.

**Code:**

```
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Matrix<T> {
    vec: Vec<T>,
    rows: usize,
    columns: usize,
}

impl<T: Clone> Matrix<T> {
    fn new(default: T, r: usize, c: usize) -> Matrix<T> {
        Matrix {
            vec: vec![default; r * c],
            rows: r,
            columns: c,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Matrix<T> {
    fn check(&self, row: usize, column: usize) {
        assert!(row < self.rows, "row out of range");
        assert!(column < self.columns, "column out of range");
    }
}

impl<T> IndexMut<(usize, usize)> for Matrix<T> {
    fn index_mut<'a>(&'a mut self, index: (usize, usize)) -> &'a mut T {
        let (r, c) = index;
        self.check(r, c);
        &mut self.vec[r * self.columns + c]
    }
}

impl<T> Index<(usize, usize)> for Matrix<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index<'a>(&'a self, index: (usize, usize)) -> &'a T {
        let (r, c) = index;
        self.check(r, c);
        &self.vec[r * self.columns + c]
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct EditPosition {
    idx: usize,
    prev: char,
    current: char,
}

impl EditPosition {
    fn new(i: usize, p: char, c: char) -> EditPosition {
        EditPosition {
            idx: i,
            prev: p,
            current: c,
        }
    }
    fn valid_twiddle(&self, other: &EditPosition) -> bool {
        self.idx > 1 && other.idx > 1 && self.current == other.prev && self.prev == other.current
    }

    fn valid_copy(&self, other: &EditPosition) -> bool {
        self.current == other.current
    }
}

use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
enum EditOp {
    Copy,
    Replace,
    Delete,
    Insert,
    Twiddle,
    Kill,
}

impl EditOp {
    fn valid(&self, i: EditPosition, j: EditPosition) -> bool {
        use EditOp::*;
        match *self {
            Copy    => i.valid_copy(&j),
            Twiddle => i.valid_twiddle(&j),
            _ => true,
        }
    }

    fn displacement(&self) -> (usize, usize) {
        use EditOp::*;
        match *self {
            Copy | Replace => (1, 1),
            Delete         => (1, 0),
            Insert         => (0, 1),
            Twiddle        => (2, 2),
            Kill           => (0, 0),
        }
    }

    fn dec(&self, d: (usize, usize)) -> (usize, usize) {
        let (i, j) = self.displacement();
        (d.0 - i, d.1 - j)
    }

    fn align<F, T>(&self,
                   mut from_itr: F,
                   mut to_itr: T,
                   new_from: &mut String,
                   new_to: &mut String)
        where F: Iterator<Item = char>,
              T: Iterator<Item = char>
    {
        fn add_white_space<I>(a: &mut String, b: &mut String, mut a_itr: I)
            where I: Iterator<Item = char>
        {
            a.push(a_itr.next().unwrap());
            b.push(' ');
        }

        use EditOp::*;
        match *self {
            Copy | Replace => {
                new_from.push(from_itr.next().unwrap());
                new_to.push(to_itr.next().unwrap());
            }
            Delete => add_white_space(new_from, new_to, from_itr),
            Insert => add_white_space(new_to, new_from, to_itr),
            _ => panic!("Operation is not suported"),
        }
    }
}

type CostMap = HashMap<EditOp, isize>;
type EditTable = Matrix<(EditOp, isize)>;

fn create_table(from_len: usize, to_len: usize, costs: &CostMap) -> EditTable {
    use EditOp::*;
    let i_cost = *(costs.get(&Insert)
        .expect("Insert most be in costs map"));
    let d_cost = *(costs.get(&Delete)
        .expect("Delete most be in costs map"));


    let mut table = EditTable::new((Kill, 0), from_len, to_len);
    for i in 1..from_len {
        table[(i, 0)] = (Delete, table[(i - 1, 0)].1 + d_cost);
    }
    for j in 1..to_len {
        table[(0, j)] = (Insert, table[(0, j - 1)].1 + i_cost);
    }
    table
}


fn edit_distance(from: &str, to: &str, costs: &CostMap) -> (isize, Operations) {
    let from_len  = from.chars().count();
    let to_len    = to.chars().count();
    let mut table = create_table(from_len + 1, to_len + 1, costs);

    let (mut ilast, mut jlast) = (' ', ' ');
    for (i, ichar) in from.chars().enumerate() {
        for (j, jchar) in to.chars().enumerate() {
            let ij   = (i + 1, j + 1);
            let ipos = EditPosition::new(ij.0, ilast, ichar);
            let jpos = EditPosition::new(ij.1, jlast, jchar);

            table[ij] = costs.iter()
                .filter(|&(o, _)| o != &EditOp::Kill)
                .filter(|&(o, _)| o.valid(ipos, jpos))
                .map(|(o, c)| (*o, table[o.dec(ij)].1 + c))
                .min_by_key(|&(_, c)| c)
                .expect("no operation was valid");
            jlast = jchar;
        }
        ilast = ichar;
    }
    add_kill(&table, costs, from_len, to_len)
}

fn add_kill(table: &EditTable,
            costs: &CostMap,
            from_len: usize,
            to_len: usize)
            -> (isize, Operations) {
    let no_kill_cost    = table[(from_len, to_len)].1;
    let (i, cost, kill) = costs.get(&EditOp::Kill)
        .map_or((from_len, no_kill_cost, None),
                |kc| min_with_kill(&table, from_len, to_len, *kc));

    (cost, build_operations(kill, &table, i, to_len))
}

type Operations = Vec<EditOp>;

fn min_with_kill(table: &EditTable,
                 from_size: usize,
                 to_size: usize,
                 kill_cost: isize)
                 -> (usize, isize, Option<EditOp>) {
    let no_kill_cost = table[(from_size, to_size)].1;
    (1..from_size)
        .map(|i| (i, table[(i, to_size)].1 + kill_cost))
        .map(|(i, c)| (i, c, Some(EditOp::Kill)))
        .chain(Some((from_size, no_kill_cost, None)).into_iter())
        .min_by_key(|&(_, cost, _)| cost)
        .unwrap()
}

fn build_operations(kill: Option<EditOp>, table: &EditTable, i: usize, j: usize) -> Operations {
    let itr = std::iter::repeat(())
        .scan((i, j), |s, _| {
            let op = table[*s].0;
            *s     = op.dec(*s);
            Some(op)
        })
        .take_while(|op| op != &EditOp::Kill);

    let mut stack: Vec<_> = kill.into_iter()
        .chain(itr)
        .collect();
    stack.reverse();
    stack
}


fn optimal_alignment(from: &str, to: &str, cost_map: &CostMap) -> (String, String) {
    let (_, ops)     = edit_distance(from, to, cost_map);
    let mut new_from = String::new();
    let mut new_to   = String::new();
    let mut from_itr = from.chars();
    let mut to_itr   = to.chars();

    for op in ops {;
        op.align(&mut from_itr, 
                 &mut to_itr, 
                 &mut new_from, 
                 &mut new_to);
    }
    (new_from, new_to)
}

fn main() {
    let mut cost_map = HashMap::new();
    cost_map.insert(EditOp::Delete, 2);
    cost_map.insert(EditOp::Insert, 2);
    cost_map.insert(EditOp::Copy, -1);
    cost_map.insert(EditOp::Replace, 1);

    let from   = "CBADDKDDBBTPPEP";
    let to     = "CGAEEDDKDDBBTEEFGKKK";
    let (f, t) = optimal_alignment(from, to, &cost_map);
    println!("{}\n{}", f, t);
}
```